# One to one with referencedColumnName mapping on wrong field

Tags: sql, spring, jpa, annotations, one-to-one

I'm facing problem on one to one relationship. I have 2 tables, one Article which has 1 FK "FICHE_ID" refrences to the second table's id Fiche(ID_FICHE) and the problem is that JPA is not mapping on the right field, it's taking ID_ARTICLE to map ID_FICHE instead of FICHE_ID.
This is the code below :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ARTICLE")
public class Article  implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="ID_ARTICLE")
Integer id=0;

@Column(name="ENTREPRISE")
private String entreprise;

@Column(name="CODE_ARTICLE")
private String code;

@Column(name="LIBELLE_ARTICLE")
private String libelle;

@Column(name="ROLE_READ")
private String role;

@Column(name="PRIX")
private int prix;

@Column(name="OBLIGATOIRE")
private String obligatoire;

@NaturalId
@Column(name="TAILLE_CODE")
private String tailleCode;

@NaturalId
@Column(name="FICHE_ID")
private Integer ficheId;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy="article")
FicheArticle fiche;
```

And

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FICHE")
public class FicheArticle {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="ID_FICHE",insertable = false,updatable = false)
private Integer id=0;
@Lob
@Column(name="FICHE",insertable = false,updatable = false)
private byte[] fiche;
@Lob
@Column(name="FICHE")
private Blob ficheBlob;
@Column(name="ENTREPRISE")
private String entreprise;
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="ID_FICHE", referencedColumnName = "FICHE_ID")  
private Article article;
```

Please, can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not positive I understand your question; but it looks like a few things need to be changed. Since the foreign key is held by the `ARTICLE` table, you cannot use `mappedBy` on the `Article.fiche` mapping. Instead, you should specify the appropriate join column on `Article.fiche` and `mappedBy` on `Fiche.article`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ARTICLE")
public class Article  implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID_ARTICLE")
Integer id = 0;

// ...

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "FICHE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID_FICHE")
FicheArticle fiche;
```

And

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FICHE")
public class FicheArticle {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID_FICHE", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Integer id = 0;

// ...

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "fiche")
@JoinColumn(name="ID_FICHE", referencedColumnName = "FICHE_ID")  
private Article article;
```

Also, I'm guessing `Article.ficheId` is *not* a `@NaturalId` for `Article`; so you should simply remove the field (and its mapping).